# Compare User-IDs with few table in db and delete all the records if the employee has been terminated more than 5 years ago

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, multithreading

I have written a SQL stored procedure to delete an employee record and for half a million records it's running forever.

I have a million records in a flat file(`.xls`) which has user_id's and their termination dates for a particular supermarket chain.

Now I have to compare this `user_ids` with a few tables in the database which does not keep track of termination dates and delete all the records if the employee has been terminated more than 5 years ago.

(These users amount to half a million records). what could be the best approach to solving this problem quickly without the DB script taking ages to run?

Comment: Please provide more detail about db like how many tables having data etc

Comment: Reference data in 4 tables have to be deleted and the size of the DB is around 12 GB.

Comment: Load the Excel data into the database and do all the work in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the file to CSV and import it into an in-memory temporary table, with the primary key as the user_id. Use the reference to this temporary table to perform the delete operation. The primary key will create an index on the field, which will speed the operation.